# docker private registry: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: docker

After creating a **private docker registry** on one of my machines, I try to push an image to it but it throws the error: `Get "https://host.domain/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

The registry was created according to the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate). If I request the same url within safari or chrome, the request gets resolved successfully, showing that the certificate is valid.

So I'm wondering: *what does docker do differently* that it can't validate my certificate?

Many thanks in advice!

Comment: Did you used a self-signed certificate to your `docker registry` ?

Comment: I don‘t think so. My domain is registered by ionos and the CA is called **DigiCert**

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: it seems that if your certificate issuer provides an *intermediate certificate* **EXPLICITLY**, it's required to chain the `domain.crt` and `intermediate.crt` by running `cat domain.cry intermediate.crt > concat-domain.crt` (for example).

Instruction coming from [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry).